# How to get an image hover a video background

Tags: javascript, html, css

So i am looking forward to have an image hover and move a bit when you also move your mouse, over a video background.

I've tried to use the code provided by *chriscoyier* on his [codepen](https://codepen.io/chriscoyier/pen/YOMJoK) page.

The result was kinda promising but not exactly what i was looking for.

[image]

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" >
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Pigu</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css">

</head>
<body>
<!-- partial:index.partial.html -->
<div class="module-jamf" id="module-jamf">
  
  <a href="#" class="jamf-container" id="jamf-container" target="_blank" rel="noopener">
    <div class="jamf-mover" id="jamf-mover">
    </div>
  </a>
  
</div>

        <video id="videoBG" poster="poster.JPG" autoplay muted loop>
            <source src="https://pigu.ro/loop_black.mp4" type="video/mp4">
        </video>
    

<!-- partial -->
  <script  src="./script.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

And to not full the page anymore with probably useless code, here would be the [stylesheet](https://pastebin.com/raw/Eu5Gh8YW) used.

Sadly, i did not manage to get it back on it's spot properly centered and with the right size.

The website in question would be "https://pigu.ro/", and all the required resources are on it as such: (background: loop_black.mp4 - logo pigicon.png)

The Pig logo should hover over the back dot in the video, yet the closest i was, i just managed to get it either above or under the video, or destroy the page more or less.

I am looking for a solution that would also be responsive to the user's display (mainly on PC).

Please let me know if you have any suggestions or ideas.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: what is back dot?